# Join a query of two tables with another table

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need help to join three tables. Somehow I could join two tables `table1` and `table2` to get desired output but I want to join 
another table to get some new related columns. 
Here is my query:

```
select 
[from_bus] as [Node], 
[from_bus_id]  as [Node_id]
from table1 
union 
select 
[to_bus] as [Node], 
[to_bus_id]  as [Node_id]
from table1
union
select 
[from_bus] as [Node], 
[from_bus_id]  as [Node_id]
from table2
union 
select 
[to_bus] as [Node], 
[to_bus_id]  as [Node_id]
from table2
```

Query Output from table1 and table2 :

```
Node Node_ID
A_22  1
A_11  2
B_33  3
C_25  4
```

Node and Node_ID are unique. 
Now, I have another table3 from which I need another column `(Zone_ref)`which contains `IDs` of respective `Zone`.

```
    table3: 
    Zone   Node_Name  Zone_ref
    A      A_22        1
    A      A_11        1
    B      B_33        3 
    B      B_44        3     
    C      C_31        4
    C      C_25        4
```

I want to have something like:

```
Node Node_ID Zone_ref
A_22  1       1
A_11  2       1
B_33  3       3
C_25  4       4
```

There are common fields where I can join the table but don't know how to integrate one query from two tables with third table. Need your suggestions. By the way  I am using access db. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nested subquery with Join. Like below:

```
select a.Node, a.Node_id, b.Zone_ref from (
 select 
 [from_bus] as [Node], 
 [from_bus_id]  as [Node_id]
 from table1 
 union 
 select 
 [to_bus] as [Node], 
 [to_bus_id]  as [Node_id]
 from table1
 union
 select 
 [from_bus] as [Node], 
 [from_bus_id]  as [Node_id]
 from table2
 union 
 select 
 [to_bus] as [Node], 
 [to_bus_id]  as [Node_id]
 from table2 ) a
INNER JOIN table3 b ON a.Node = b.Node_Name
```

Comment: Works fine! Thank you Sonal.

Comment: Welcome @M.Thakur, Enjoy Coding!

Comment: @ Sonal Borkar Hi, a small question: Again if I need to join 4th table then I modified query `select a.Node, a.Node_id, b.Zone_ref, c.latitude , c.longitude (
 select 
 code remains as it is  ) a
INNER JOIN table3 b ON a.Node = b.Node_Name AND  table4 c ON b.Zone_ref = c.Zone_id` ` Zone_ref`  from ` table3`  and ` Zone_id`  from table4 are common fields. I used this query but gave error like "Missing operator". Could you please tell me where it goes wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sonal, I modified code again but could not give me perfect result. It misses some rows. If you have some time could you please have a look over the code ? Thank you. `select d.Node, d.Node_id, d.Zone_ref, c.latitude,c.longitude  from 
(select a.Node, a.Node_id, b.Zone_ref  from (
 select 
Code remains as it is ) a
INNER JOIN table3 b ON a.Node = b.Zone_ref) d
INNER JOIN table4 c ON c.Zone_id = d.Zone_ref` Here c is new 4th table.

Comment: @M.Thakur What are the columns in 4th table and what is the desired output?

Comment: Hi @Sonal, This should be final output where I can add lattitude and longitude of respective zones. Where 4th table has common field `zone_id` This is final output: `Node Node_ID Zone_ref latitude longitude
                                 A_22  1       1                xx     yy
                                 A_11  2       1         xx  yy
                                 B_33  3       3         xx  yy
                                 C_25  4       4         xx  yy`                            XX and YY are just arbitrary numbers.Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sonal, now it's working fine. Actually the zone_ID and Zone_ref had different data types (like one had integer and other had integer with two decimals so it couldn't recognized at some rows. But now it's working fine. Thank you.

Comment: @M.Thakur Great Thanks, Enjoy Coding!